# Как сделать поле для даты рождения?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

По ходу регистрации пользователь заполняет поля и одним из них является поле для ввода даты рождения. Сейчас стоит просто type="text" видел, что есть type="date", но он в каждом браузере выглядит по разному. Placeholder не использую, т.к. по умолчанию поля все пустые(так утвердили дизайн). Мне нужно, что бы дата вводилась только с разделителями(с точкой или слешем, неважно). И чтобы его можно было стилизировать через CSS или JS. Может подскажете что-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете jQuery, то одним из решений может быть использование компонентов интерфейса **jQuery UI**, в данном случае **Datepicker**:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Для стилизации можно использовать [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте type="date". Данный тайп пока не поддерживается Мозиллой. Для нее скачайте и подключите библиотеку modernizr и jQuery-UI:

```
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.52481.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

И добавьте скрипт:
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {$("#id").datepicker();}
где id - id элемента с типом date.